# Set integer array in CUDA to -1 effectively

Tags: memory, cuda, initialization

I have a pointer ptr to CUDA array of integers, and want to initialize all elements of this array to -1 effectively **from host code**. How do I can achieve this?

At first look, cudaMemset doesn't fit, because it works on per-byte basis...

Answer (score 4):

`-1` is represented as `0xffffffff` for 32-bit signed integers, see [this Wikipedia page on Two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) for more information. Therefore, you can just set each byte to `0xff`, as demonstrated below:

```cpp
cudaMemset(ptr, 0xff, size);
```

Please note you are not guaranteed your `cudaMemset` will not be converted to a kernel by the CUDA driver, i.e. the driver can execute GPU code to execute your memset. Also, this approach might confuse external readers as it is not immediately clear what you are trying to achieve, which is why **I recommend using a CUDA kernel to initialize your array**.